# Riemann Context for Hadoop to send metrics to Riemann using metrics2 interface

Tags: hadoop, metrics, hadoop-yarn, riemann

Is there a library which can be integrated with the different Hadoop components (Namenode, datanode, jobtracker, tasktracker) as well as the Hadoop 2 components (Resource Manager) to send metrics to Riemann?